# International Journal

Tags: data-mining, nlp

I would like to post a paper in International Conference on Soft Computing. I want to know whether the journal is a reputed journal.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it [here](http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=1712&area=0&year=2013&country=US&order=sjr&min=0&min_type=cd&page=0). At least that one is in the list.